# Get index of string scan results in ruby

Tags: ruby, indexing

I want to get the index as well as the results of a scan

```
"abab".scan(/a/)
```

I would like to have not only

```
=> ["a", "a"]
```

but also the index of those matches

```
[1, 3]
```

any suggestion?

Comment: Hi - sorry for massive spam but http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/74083/korean-language could use you if you're not there already!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Try this:

```
res = []
"abab".scan(/a/) do |c|
  res << [c, $~.offset(0)[0]]
end

res.inspect # => [["a", 0], ["a", 2]]
```

Comment: @Todd's answer is right. However if you prefer to avoid using the slightly cryptic special variables like `$~` then `Regexp.last_match` is equivalent. i.e. you can say `Regexp.last_match.offset(0)[0]`

Comment: or even `Regexp.last_match.offset(0).first`

Comment: For those wondering how these methods work, see [`MatchData#offset`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/MatchData.html#method-i-offset) and [`Regexp::last_match`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Regexp.html#method-c-last_match)

Comment: Or `"abab".scan(/a/).inject([]){ |res, a| res << [a, Regexp.last_match.offset(0).first] }`

Answer (score 6):

There's a gotcha to look out for here, depending on the behaviour you expect.

If you search for `/dad/` in `"dadad"` you'd only get `[["dad",0]]` because `scan` advances to the end of each match when it finds one (which is wrong to me).

I came up with this alternative:

```
def scan_str(str, pattern)
  res = []
  (0..str.length).each do |i|
    res << [Regexp.last_match.to_s, i] if str[i..-1] =~ /^#{pattern}/
  end
  res
end
```

If you wanted you could also do a similar thing with [StringScanner](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/StringScanner.html) from the standard library, it might be faster for long strings.

Answer (score 4):

Very similar to what @jim has said and works a bit better for longer strings:

```
def matches str, pattern
    arr = []
    while (str && (m = str.match pattern))      
        offset = m.offset(0).first 
        arr << offset + (arr[-1] ? arr[-1] + 1 : 0)
        str = str[(offset + 1)..-1]
    end
    arr
end
```

Answer (score 1):

It surprised me that there isn't any method similar to `String#scan` which would return array of `MatchData` objects, similar to `String#match`. So, if you like monkey-patching, you can combine this with Todd's solution (`Enumerator` is introduced in 1.9):

```
class Regexp
  def scan str
    Enumerator.new do |y|
      str.scan(self) do
        y << Regexp.last_match
      end
    end
  end
end
#=> nil
/a/.scan('abab').map{|m| m.offset(0)[0]}
#=> [0, 2]
```

Comment: NoMethodError: undefined method `scan' for