# Finding # occurrences of a character in a string in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string, methods

I'm looking for the Ruby method (1.9...) that can help me find the number of occurrences of a character in a string. I'm looking for all occurrences, not just the first one.

For example: "Melanie is a noob"
There are two occurrences of the letter 'a'.
What would be the Ruby method I could use in order to find this?

I've been using [Ruby-doc.org](http://Ruby-doc.org) as a reference and the `scan` method in the `String: class` caught my eye. The wording is a bit difficult for me to understand, so I don't really grasp the concept of `scan`.

**Edit: I was able to solve this using `scan`. [I shared a few solutions in a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=meuPRXSbmjw) on how I achieved it.**

Comment: Do you want the number of occurrences, or the index values of the occurrences in the string? Knowing how many is often useful, but usually the next question is "where are they?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve this by passing a string through `scan` as shown in another answer.

For example:

```
string = 'This is an example'
puts string.count('e')
```

Outputs:

```
2
```

I was also able to pull the occurrences by using scan and passing a sting through instead of regex which varies slightly from another answer but was helpful in order to avoid regex.

```
string = 'This is an example'
puts string.scan('e')
```

Outputs:

```
['e','e']
```

I explored these methods further in a [video I created](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=meuPRXSbmjw) after I figured it out.

Answer (score 154):

If you just want the number of a's:

```
puts "Melanie is a noob".count('a')  #=> 2
```

[Docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-count) for more details.

Comment: why it doesn't work with dots? Example "voyage.localhost.com".count('www.') => 2. How this can be?

Comment: @Gediminas `count` counts chars, not strings.  "voyage.localhost.com".count('www.') is the same as  "voyage.localhost.com".count('w.') and since there are no w's and two dots the result is 2.

Comment: Any chance you could add [a link to the docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-count)?

Comment: I was initially quite shocked by this answer, then I saw that Melanie used the example first. Good answer!

Comment: @Hubro and AJFaraday: Ha!  Yeah, I'd been _really_ impressed if, when the OP said "occurrences of a character", she meant "character" as a pun _and_ she used a sample string like, oh let's say "Trump" - you know, such that the "occurrences of _a_ character" in "Trump" would be 0.  ;)

Comment: I love Ruby for things like this method! Simple and useful :)

Answer (score 55):

This link from a question asked previously should help
[scanning a string in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520208/get-index-of-string-scan-results-in-ruby)

scan returns all the occurrences of a string in a string as an array, so

```
"Melanie is a noob".scan(/a/)
```

will return

```
["a","a"]
```

Comment: This is the answer i was looking for :)

Comment: `scan` works with simple Strings, too, so `scan('a')` can used as well