# How to match given characters in string

Tags: ruby, string

Given:

```
fruits = %w[Banana Apple Orange Grape]
chars = 'ep'
```

how can I print all elements of `fruits` that have all characters of `chars`? I tried the following:

```
fruits.each{|fruit| puts fruit if !(fruit=~/["#{chars}"]/i).nil?)}
```

but I see `'Orange'` in the result, which does not have the `'p'` character in it.

Comment: A small thing: `!(a =~ <regex>)` is the same as `a !~ <regex>`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding occurrences of a character in a string with Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5409587/finding-occurrences-of-a-character-in-a-string-with-ruby)

Comment: @Trix, I don't see a connection.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Even more, negation is not at all necessary.

Comment: @sawa, I confess to not examining the context; it was meant as a general comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just for fun, here's how you might do this with a regular expression, thanks to the magic of positive lookahead:

```
fruits = %w[Banana Apple Orange Grape]
p fruits.grep(/(?=.*e)(?=.*p)/i)
# => ["Apple", "Grape"]
```

This is nice and succinct, but the regex is a bit occult, and it gets worse if you want to generalize it:

```
def match_chars(arr, chars)
  expr_parts = chars.chars.map {|c| "(?=.*#{Regexp.escape(c)})" }
  arr.grep(Regexp.new(expr_parts.join, true))
end

p match_chars(fruits, "ar")
# => ["Orange", "Grape"]
```

Also, I'm pretty sure this would be outperformed by most or all of the other answers.

Comment: Very clever, and instructive!

Comment: Uh oh. I didn't intend for this to be the accepted answer; it's far from ideal for the reasons mentioned. @CarySwoveland's is the better answer. When I'm at a computer I might change this to Community Wiki.

Answer (score 6):

```
p fruits.select { |fruit| chars.delete(fruit.downcase).empty? }
["Apple", "Grape"]
```

[String#delete](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-delete) returns a copy of `chars` with all characters in `delete`'s argument deleted.

Answer (score 3):

```
fruits = ["Banana", "Apple", "Orange", "Grape"]
chars = 'ep'.chars

fruits.select { |fruit| (fruit.split('') & chars).length == chars.length }

#=> ["Apple", "Grape"]
```

Comment: Prefer `'ep'.chars` to `'ep'.split('')`.

Comment: @Jordan cool beans, I like that too. I will edit my post to reflect the change :)

Comment: @Jordan, you probably also prefer `chars` to `'ep'.scan /./`.

Answer (score 2):

```
chars.each_char.with_object(fruits.dup){|e, a| a.select!{|s| s.include?(e)}}
# => ["Apple", "Grape"]
```

To print:

```
puts chars.each_char.with_object(fruits.dup){|e, a| a.select!{|s| s.include?(e)}}
```

Comment: @CarySwoveland I hope you are happy.

Comment: @NodirNasirov So what?

Answer (score 2):

I'm an absolute beginner, but here's what worked for me

```
fruits = %w[Banana Apple Orange Grape] 
chars = 'ep'

fruits.each {|fruit| puts fruit if fruit.include?('e') && fruit.include?('p')}
```

Comment: That works, but the OP probably wanted to do it for an arbitrary string `chars`.

Comment: @sawa understood. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: You can get rid of word `puts` as it is not needed.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one more way to do this:

```
fruits.select {|f| chars.downcase.chars.all? {|c| f.downcase.include?(c)} }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, first split all characters into an Array ( `chars.split("")` ) and after check if all are present into word.

```
fruits.select{|fruit| chars.split("").all? {|char| fruit.include?(char)}}
#=> ["Apple", "Grape"]
```