# Regex: text before multiple matches

Tags: ruby, regex

**Idea**. Given the string, return all the matches (with overlaps) and the text before these matches.

**Example**. For the text `atatgcgcatatat` and the query `atat` there are three matches, and the desired output is `atat`, `atatgcgcatat` and `atatgcgcatatat`.

**Problem**. I use Ruby 2.2 and `String#scan` method to get multiple matches. I've tried to use lookahead, but the regex `/(?=(.*?atat))/` returns every substring that ends with `atat`. There must be some regex magic to solve this problem, but I can't figure out the right spell.

Comment: No way to do it with just one go, I guess. The matches are not just overlapping, they start at the same index. You need to move index to each match start upon success to see if there can be other matches not equal to the previous one.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments!

Comment: reverse the string, and use the same pattern.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I've tried the idea of reversing the string, but it seems rather ugly to me: `"atatgcatatat".reverse.scan(/(?=(tata.*))/).flatten.map(&:reverse).reverse`.

Comment: My vote for best answer goes to sawa. @Nakilon gets an assist (whether needed or not).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the nature and purpose of regex, there is no way to do that. When a regex matches text, there is no way to include the same text in another match. Therefore, the best option that I can think of is to use a look-behind to find the ending position of each match:

```
(?<=atat)
```

With your example input of `atatgcgcatatat`, that would return the following three matches:

- Position 4, Length 0
- Position 12, Length 0
- Position 14, Length 0

You could then loop through those results, get the position for each one, and then get the sub-string that starts at the beginning of the input string and ends at that position. If you don't know how to get the positions of each match, you may find the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5241653/ruby-regex-match-and-get-positions-of) helpful.

Comment: But how do I get multiple matches?

`"atatgcgcatatat".scan /.*atat/  #=> ["atatgcgcatatat"]`

Comment: Thank you, that was helpful!

Since there's no option to get the output in just one go, I've also found a way to get the result, and it's slightly different from what you've proposed. I'll post it as a separate answer.

Comment: Thanks, @Nakilon, that was useful!

Answer (score 4):

I believe this is at least better than the OP's answer:

```
text = "atatgcgcatatat"
query = "atat"

res = []
text.scan(/(?=#{query})/){res.push($` + query)}                                  #`
res # => ["atat", "atatgcgcatat", "atatgcgcatatat"]
```

Comment: It definitely is!
I implemented other ideas in Ruby too and added them to my answer.

Comment: I guess, there's no need for intermediate array: `text.to_enum(:scan, /(?<=atat)/).map { $\` }`

Comment: You could use `tap` as I did: `[].tap { |a| text.scan(/(?=#{query})/) {a << $\` + query} } #=> ["atat", "atatgcgcatat", "atatgcgcatatat"]`.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
str = 'atatgcgcatatat'
target = 'atat'

[].tap do |a|
  str.gsub(/(?=#{target})/) { a << str[0, $~.end(0)+target.size] }
end
  #=> ["atat", "atatgcgcatat", "atatgcgcatatat"]
```

Notice that the string returned by `gsub` is discarded.

Answer (score 0):

It seems, there's no way to solve the problem in just one go.

One possible solution is to use [this knowledge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520208/get-index-of-string-scan-results-in-ruby) to get indices of matches when using `String#scan`, and then return the array of sliced strings:

```
def find_by_end text, query
    res = []
    n = query.length
    text.scan( /(?=(#{query}))/ ) do |m|
        res << text.slice(0, $~.offset(0).first + n)
    end
    res
end

find_by_end "atatgcgcatatat", "atat" #=> ["atat", "atatgcgcatat", "atatgcgcatatat"]
```

A slightly different solution was proposed by @StevenDoggart. Here's a nice and short code which uses [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4274388/how-to-get-indexes-of-all-occurrences-of-a-pattern-in-a-string/4274503#4274503) hack to solve the problem:

```
"atatgcatatat".to_enum(:scan, /(?<=atat)/).map { $` }                         #`
#=> ["atat", "atatgcatat", "atatgcatatat"]
```

As @CasimiretHippolyte notes, reversing the string might help to solve the problem. It actually does, but it's hardly the prettiest solution:

```
"atatgcatatat".reverse.scan(/(?=(tata.*))/).flatten.map(&:reverse).reverse
#=> ["atat", "atatgcatat", "atatgcatatat"]
```