# How to get Index of Nokogiri node in HTML Source?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

Suppose my HTML looks like this:

```
html = '<HTML><BODY><a id="id1">test</a><a id="id2">test2</a></BODY></HTML>'
```

I extract the 2nd link: `node = doc.css("a#id2")[0]`

How do I get the starting index of this node HTML in the HTML source? Which is 32?

```
html.slice(32, SOMETHING) = '<a id="id2">...'
```

Note: I know this is a trivial example but the solution should address cases where the node I extract isn't unique in the HTML.

Comment: You can convert the doc to a String with .text and use this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/3520277/2067375 to scan the string by a regular expresion and You will get the starting position of each match.